# How to get all records from a huggingface dataset in a single csv?

Tags: python, dataset, huggingface, huggingface-datasets

The cnn_dailymail dataset contains 3 fields - ID,Text,Highlights

I wanted to get all the records in the [cnn_dailymail](https://huggingface.co/datasets/cnn_dailymail) dataset in a single csv , but have been unsuccessful in finding a way.

Currently I have downloaded the dataset locally from [here](https://huggingface.co/datasets/cnn_dailymail/tree/main/data) (the file called cnn_stories.tgz).
I have unzipped the .tgz and got a folder of `.story` files that has the text and summary for each record in the dataset. Because there are 100k records, I have got 100k `.story` files

The problem with such extraction is I have got 100k story files , each has a text and it's summary. Ideally I wanted it in a csv format where there are 2 columns - one for the article and the next for the highlights -- and he csv to contain 100k rows.

I want to only do this using a locally downloaded dataset(due to proxy issues in my work system)

***Alternative way to ask the question***: How to use load_dataset() funtion from the datasets library to load a dataset from a locally downloaded `.tgz` file

Answer (score 1):

You could run the following code in Google Colab (takes time!) then either download the files or save then to your Google Drive.

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
cnn_builder = tfds.summarization.cnn_dailymail.CnnDailymail()
cnn_info = cnn_builder.info
cnn_builder.download_and_prepare()
datasets = cnn_builder.as_dataset()
train_dataset, test_dataset = datasets["train"], datasets["test"]
print(len(train_dataset))
print(len(test_dataset))
train_df = tfds.as_dataframe(train_dataset)
test_df = tfds.as_dataframe(test_dataset)
train_df.to_csv("daily_mail_train.csv")
test_df.to_csv("daily_mail_test.csv")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Apologies mate - tensorflow_datasets is blocked for me internally (in my work system).. Would you know a way to directly load a dataset from *cnn_dailymail.tgz* file that I have downloaded locally ?

Comment: Run it in Google Colab dont run it locally. Then you can download the csv files generated

Comment: Your other choice is to manually process and create the csv files as detailed here `https://github.com/abisee/cnn-dailymail`